# Biblatex with autoyear, display first name

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

i am in help with Biblatex for my recent work.
So my university has some weird requirements for citation, they require me to write citations the following: (vgl.{firstName} {lastName} et. al. ({year})) if the numbers of authors are above 2.

Else it should be displayed (vgl. {firstName} {lastName}, {firstName2} {lastName2}. ({year}))

So i came up with following, but im unable to add the firstname to the citation

```
%Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage[ style=authoryear, sorting=nyt,  maxnames=2, useprefix=true]{ }

\def \citedefault #1[#2]{(vgl.  \citeauthor*{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), #2)}
\def \citenopage #1{(vgl.  \citeauthor*{#1} (\citeyear{#1}))}
\def \citefigure #1[#2]{\citeauthor*{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), #2}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{urlseen = {abgerufen am}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
}
\usepackage[csdisplay=true]{csquotes}
```

I use the following code in the .tex file:

```
\citenopage{wirtschaftslexikonGeldmenge}
```

my literatur.bib file looks the following:

```
@online{wirtschaftslexikonGeldmenge,
    author = {Budzinski, Oliver  and Jasper, Jörg and Michler, Albrecht},
    date = {2018-02-19},
    language = {german},
    title = {Geldmenge},
    url = {https://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/definition/geldmenge-32198/version-255744},
    urldate = {2022-04-30},
}
```

and the output is the following:

```
(vgl. Budzinski et al. (2018))
```

but my university requires: it the following way:

```
(vgl. Oliver Budzinski et al. (2018))
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change the `labelname` name format.

In general it is not a good idea to combine several `\...cite` commands into one. Usually there are more elegant ways to achieve the desired result. In this case `biblatex-ext` can help.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxcitenames=2,
  useprefix=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{(}{)}

\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[vgl.][380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[vgl.][]{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite[23]{companion}
sit \autocite{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (vgl. Emma Sigfridsson, Ulf Ryde (1998), S. 380) ipsum (vgl. Martha Nussbaum (1978)) dolor (Michel Goossens et al. (1994), S. 23) sit (Ingrid de Geer (1985))]